# VS 2022 unable to find .g.cs autogenerated files

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, auto-generate

I'm unable to build my current project in `Visual Studio 2022` since I updated to `17.2.` version.

It complains about not finding autogenerated `.g.cs` files which some times are in the `obj` folder and sometimes are not.

So the initial problem of: why VS 2022 does not find the autogenerated files, we also have the extra problem of: why sometimes are not those files not generated? As many of you would have suspected those files belong to `XAML` files.

On the other hand `Visual Studio 2019` can cleanly build the project without any problem.

Many `VS 2022` updates have not solved my current problem.

Comment: Is there a specific file it is looking for (such as the Global Usings file)?

Comment: not specific but xaml files are affected